# realloc: Not enough space

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management

Windows 7, 64bit, MinGW toolset, following code:

```
m_data = reinterpret_cast<SampleType *>(realloc(m_data, m_size + v));  
if (NULL == m_data){  
    perror ("realloc failed");  
    exit(-1);  
}
```

fails with the message `realloc failed: Not enough space`
It happens even if I asked 100 bytes more. And no matter whether I use malloc (with the correspondind pointer reaasignment) or realloc. I always get the same.
The computer reports over 1GB available free memory.

Above is fragment of the method. Below is its entire code.
The point is that this method allocates memory first time when `this` method has m_data equal to `NULL` and enlarges it in cosenquent calls. So, pls, see below

```
Wave & operator+= (const Wave wave){
    if (NULL != m_data){
        m_data = reinterpret_cast<SampleType *>(realloc(m_data, m_size + wave.DataSize()));
        if (NULL == m_data){
        perror ("realloc failed");
        exit(-1);
        }
    } else {
        m_data = reinterpret_cast<SampleType *>(malloc(wave.DataSize()));
        m_size = 0; // just for sure
    }
    /* this code fragment I used instead of realloc's one to prove that realloc is not a root of error cause
    SampleType *t_buf = reinterpret_cast<SampleType *>(malloc(m_size + wave.DataSize()));
    if (!t_buf) {perror ("malloc failed"); exit(-1);}
    memcpy (t_buf, m_data, m_size);
    free (m_data);
    m_data = t_buf;
    */
    memcpy (m_data + m_size, wave.SampleBuffer(), wave.DataSize());
    m_size += wave.DataSize();
    return *this;
};
```

So, in first time a memory is allocated using malloc. Don't doubt.

Debugger session trace.

```
Breakpoint 2, _fu17___ZSt4cout () at ../sound_windows/Sound.h:192  
192             if (NULL != m_data){  
(gdb) print *this  
$2 = {static CHANNEL_NUMBER = <optimized out>, m_format = {wFormatTag = 1, nChannels = 2,nSamplesPerSec = 44100, nAvgBytesPerSec = 176400, nBlockAlign = 4,  
    wBitsPerSample = 16, cbSize = 18}, m_duration = 0, m_data = 0x0, m_size = 0}  
(gdb) cont  
Continuing.  

Breakpoint 2, _fu17___ZSt4cout () at ../sound_windows/Sound.h:192  
192             if (NULL != m_data){  
(gdb) print *this  
$3 = {static CHANNEL_NUMBER = <optimized out>, m_format = {wFormatTag = 1, nChannels = 2,nSamplesPerSec = 44100, nAvgBytesPerSec = 176400, nBlockAlign = 4,  
    wBitsPerSample = 16, cbSize = 18}, m_duration = 0.00451559993, m_data = 0x75d9e0, m_size = 800}  
(gdb) cont  
Continuing.  
tried to allocate 800+100 bytes  
realloc failed: Not enough space  
[Inferior 1 (process 6132) exited with code 037777777777]
```

Comment: What is the value of `m_size + v` you see under debugger stepping onto that line?

Comment: You are sure m_data was already allocated? Also, what exactly gives the 'Not enough space' error? I only see the "realloc failed" that you report through `perror`, `realloc` could return NULL for other reasons.

Comment: Same happens if you remove that reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @KillianDS: yes, I sure m_data was already allocated. And the message happened right after realloc retuns `NULL`. So that's all information I have regarding the.

Comment: Was m_data allocated using `malloc` or something else? `realloc` only reallocates memory allocated with `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of cause of the error was stack destruction happened due to mess in memory addressing in memory management functions. For example, in the following code line

```
memcpy (m_data + m_size, wave.SampleBuffer(), wave.DataSize());
```

`m_data + m_size` means not what it was intended because `m_data` points to a two byte size type while `m_size` is size in bytes. So `m_data + m_size` offsets poninter not to the end of `m_data` but on to the distance twice far.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the existing `m_data` was not allocated directly with `malloc`. `realloc` only reallocates blocks originally allocated with `malloc`.

This is because it uses knowledge of the internal data structures of the heap. If the block is not from the heap, if you are lucky you will get a message, if you are unlucky your program will just crash.

The "not enough space" message is just the generic return from allocation failure.

***EDIT:*** In the expanded version, did you initialize `m_data` to `NULL` in the constructor? This does not happen automatically, and if you don't do it, it will generally contain a garbage value.

In other words, The branch `if (NULL != m_data){` will never be hit, since m_data doesn't start out as `NULL` unless you initialize it.

Comment: OK, guys, see entire code and a corresponding comments in initial question.

Comment: @OlegG, See what? If you are editing be sure to show where m_data was allocated.

Comment: @OlegG, I added more to the answer.

Comment: Yes I initialized m_data to NULL in constructor. It was checked.

Comment: @olegG, Stick a breakpoint on that line and check it in the debugger.

Comment: I've extended question with debugger trace. Please note, that there are two consequent passes through 192'th line `(if (NULL != m_data){`. the first pass gives NULL and 0m the second one gives another values.

Comment: I am out of ideas then. Sorry.

Comment: This answer is basically false. according to [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) from cplusplus.com, "In case that ptr is a null pointer, the function behaves like malloc, assigning a new block of size bytes and returning a pointer to its beginning."